# What is the equivalent to ReplaySubject (RxJava) in Reactor for spring webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rx-java, reactor-netty

What is the equivalent to ReplaySubject (RxJava) in Reactor for spring webflux?.

I need a hot observable channel who can have N subscribers and save the previous published elements like ReplaySubject in rxJava. 
Thanks for your comments, im using Spring webflux.

I dont find any like ReplaySubject in Reactor.

If there is no implementation of ReplaySubject, how could i implement?, i have some code like:

```
class ReplayFlux<T> {
private val elements: List<T> = emptyList()
private val currentSubscriptions: List<FluxSink<T>> = emptyList()

fun publish(element: T){
    elements.plus(element)
    currentSubscriptions.forEach { 
        it.next(element)
    }
}

fun subscribe(): Flux<T>{
    return Flux.create {fluxSink -> 
        currentSubscriptions.plus(fluxSink)
        elements.forEach {element -> 
            fluxSink.next(element)
        }
    }
}

fun finish(){ currentSubscriptions.forEach { it.complete() } }
}
```

Obviously this is not thread safe, someone have a better imp. If you think this is not so bad imp, what thread safe data structures should you use in this case?

Comment: If you go to their [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/index.html) and start typing in `Replay` into the search box, see what you get.

Comment: my bad, thanks! There is a ReplayProcessor.